# ruby GTK tcp producing core dumps

Tags: ruby, networking, tcp, gtk

i've problems with core dumps using ruby, gtk and tcp connections. my application is much larger, but here a minimized version:

GTK code (is also attached):

#####################################################

```
require 'gtk3'
require 'cairo'

class DummyArray
  def initialize
    @array=[

"M",2,48.83,1.95,"L",8,50.55,0.0,62.27,0.0,63.91,5.0,48.83,1.95,"M",2,0.0,22.42,"L",8,0.0,16.95,9.77,13.2,7.27,28.44,0.0,22.42,"M",2,5.39,49.61,"L",8,0.0,48.52,0.0,35.63,0.47,35.08,5.39,49.61,"M",2,0.0,80.7,"L",6,0.0,68.28,9.38,70.31,0.0,80.7,"M",2,90.23,46.56,"L",6,100.0,35.55,100.0,48.52,90.23,46.56,"M",2,100.0,16.95,"L",6,100.0,22.42,95.47,18.67,100.0,16.95,"M",2,100.0,68.28,

"L",8,100.0,80.78,99.14,81.72,94.45,67.11,100.0,68.28,"M",2,50.55,100.0,"L",6,58.98,90.47,62.27,100.0,50.55,100.0,"M",2,23.44,78.67,"L",6,33.59,67.19,38.52,81.72,23.44,78.67,"M",2,40.47,15.39,"L",6,25.39,12.34,35.63,0.86,40.47,15.39,"M",2,59.61,39.77,"L",6,59.14,24.38,72.66,31.56,59.61,39.77,"M",2,45.78,36.95,"L",6,55.23,36.48,50.94,45.0,45.78,36.95,

"M",2,48.98,24.38,"L",6,43.67,16.41,53.2,15.86,48.98,24.38,"M",2,22.58,10.08,"L",6,13.52,13.13,15.47,3.75,22.58,10.08,"M",2,18.28,30.47,"L",6,21.33,39.53,11.95,37.58,18.28,30.47,"M",2,25.23,40.86,"L",6,26.41,25.55,39.06,34.22,25.23,40.86,"M",2,13.67,63.13,"L",6,13.13,47.73,26.64,54.92,13.67,63.13,"M",2,17.66,68.52,"L",6,21.72,77.19,12.11,76.25,17.66,68.52,"M",2,52.34,49.06,

"L",6,44.14,62.11,36.95,48.52,52.34,49.06,"M",2,52.42,79.84,"L",6,60.08,66.56,67.73,79.84,52.42,79.84,"M",2,47.42,76.25,"L",6,42.19,68.28,51.72,67.73,47.42,76.25,"M",2,79.14,31.48,"L",6,87.11,26.17,87.73,35.7,79.14,31.48,"M",2,81.64,20.08,"L",6,74.92,6.25,90.23,7.34,81.64,20.08,"M",2,67.97,10.86,"L",6,68.52,20.39,59.92,16.09,67.97,10.86,"M",2,73.59,73.36,"L",6,81.48,68.2,82.11,77.73,73.59,73.36,

"M",2,63.59,49.06,"L",6,64.22,58.59,55.62,54.3,63.59,49.06,"M",2,79.53,43.83,"L",6,84.45,58.36,69.38,55.31,79.53,43.83,"M",2,90.23,95.16,"L",6,92.19,85.78,99.3,92.11,90.23,95.16,"M",2,86.17,81.48,"L",6,82.34,96.33,71.41,85.55,86.17,81.48,"M",2,22.11,97.34,"L",6,6.8,97.34,14.45,84.06,22.11,97.34,"M",2,38.2,93.05,"L",6,29.14,96.09,31.09,86.72,38.2,93.05,
      "Z",0
    ]
  end
  def render(cr)
    i= 0
    size= @array.size

    while i < size
      e= @array[i]
      case e
      when 'M', 'L'
        count= @array[i+1]
        j= i + 2
        i= j + count
        while j < i
          x= @array[j]
          y= @array[j+1]
          if e == 'M'
            cr.move_to(x, y)
          else
            cr.line_to(x, y)
          end
          j += 2
        end
      when 'Z'
        count= @array[i+1]
        j= i + 2
        i= j + count
        cr.close_path
      else
        raise
      end
    end
  end
end

class ArtScrollCanvas < Gtk::Grid
  def initialize
    super

    @user_zoom= 1.0
    @darea = Gtk::DrawingArea.new

    @darea.hexpand= true
    @darea.vexpand= true

    @darea.signal_connect('configure-event') do
      print "\n darea_configure_callback"
      update_adjustments_and_paint(0.0, 0.0)
    end

    @darea.signal_connect "draw" do |_, cr|
      paint(cr)
    end

    attach(@darea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    update_adjustments_and_paint(0.0, 0.0)
  end

  def update_adjustments_and_paint(dx= 0.0, dy= 0.0)
    @darea.queue_draw_area(0, 0, @darea.allocation.width, @darea.allocation.height)
  end

  def paint(cr)
    cr.set_source_rgba(1, 1, 1, 1)
    cr.paint

    cr.set_source_rgba(1, 0, 0, 1)
    DummyArray.new.render(cr)
    #DummyDirect.new.render(cr)

    cr.fill
  end
end

class ArtApplicationWindow < Gtk::ApplicationWindow
  def initialize(application)
    super(application)
    signal_connect('destroy') do
      #Gtk.main_quit
      application.quit
    end
    set_title 'Art'
    set_size_request(600, 400)
    @canvas = ArtScrollCanvas.new

    @vbox = Gtk::Box.new(:vertical, 0)
    @vbox.pack_start(@canvas, :expand => true, :fill => true, :padding => 0)
    add(@vbox)
    show_all
  end
end # ArtApplicationWindow

class ArtApp < Gtk::Application
  def initialize
    super("org.gtk.exampleapp", :handles_open)

    signal_connect('activate') do |application|
      window = ArtApplicationWindow.new(application)
      window.present
    end
  end
end

begin
  ss = Gio::SocketService.new
  ss.add_inet_port(4321)

  ss.signal_connect("incoming") do |_, conn, _|
    print "\n#############################################################"
    print "\nconn.local_address: ", conn.local_address
    print "\nconn.local_address.family: ", conn.local_address.family
    print "\nconn.remote_address: ", conn.remote_address
    print "\nconn.class: ", conn.class
    print "\nconn.input_stream.fd: ", conn.input_stream.fd
    print "\nconn.input_stream.socket.fd: ", conn.input_stream.socket.fd

    # prevents closing the connection (at least in c code)
    Gtk::Loader.reference_gobject(conn)
    Gtk::Loader.reference_gobject(conn.input_stream)
    Gtk::Loader.reference_gobject(conn.input_stream.socket)
    Gtk::Loader.reference_gobject(conn.output_stream)
    Gtk::Loader.reference_gobject(conn.output_stream.socket)

    channel= GLib::IOChannel.new(conn.input_stream.socket.fd)
    channel.add_watch(GLib::IOChannel::IN) do
      print "\n>>> ", conn.input_stream.socket.fd
      len= conn.input_stream.socket.available_bytes
      input= conn.input_stream.read(len)
      print "\ninput= ", input

      conn.output_stream.write("OK\n")
      GLib::Source::CONTINUE
      true
    end
    true
  end

  ss.start
end

GLib::Timeout.add(10000) do
  print "\ntimer"
  GLib::Source::CONTINUE
end


app = ArtApp.new
app.run
```

#################################################
SIMPLE client:

```
require 'socket'

class Comm
  def initialize(socket, verbose: false)
    @socket= socket
    @sio= StringIO.new
    @verbose= verbose
  end

  def close
    @socket.close
  end

  def <<(str)
    @sio << str
  end

  def send
    str= @sio.string
    @socket.write(str)
    print "\n>>>\nsending: ", str if @verbose
    @sio.reopen
    res= @socket.readline
    print "\nres= \"", res, "\"" if @verbose
    res
  end
end

server_socket = TCPSocket.open("localhost", 4321)
comm= Comm.new(server_socket, verbose: true)
i= 1000000
while true
  i += 1
  comm << i.to_s
  comm.send
  sleep(0.025)  # 40 per s
end
```

in the beginning everything seems ok, but after the client is launched resizing the GTK window leads to core dumps after approx. 1000 messages (sometimes much less, but sometimes much later). Shortening the @array in DummyArray leads to less core dumps, therefore the array is that large.

i've read
https://ruby-gnome2.osdn.jp/hiki.cgi?tips_threads
but don't know how this would apply to my program ...

cheers

artur

Comment: Please make a [mre].

Comment: this is(!) a minimal example, removing more parts doesn't lead to (fast) core dumps anymore ...

Answer (score 1):

using a global array

```
$channels= []
```

and adding each new channel to it

```
channel= GLib::IOChannel.new(conn.input_stream.socket.fd)
$channels << channel
```

seems to prevent garbage collecting the channel (not well documented :-(, this answer came from the ruby-gnome2 mailing list